# ant debug, and sdk.dir

Tags: android, ant, cocos2d-x

I have a problem to generate the Android APK file.

When I run `ant debug` compilation work fine, but when I run `ant debug`

I have following error:

```
iMac:proj.android smartmind$ ant debug
Buildfile: /Users/smartmind/Works/Smallthing/cocos2d-x/samples/HelloCpp/proj.android/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/smartmind/Works/Smallthing/cocos2d-x/samples/HelloCpp/proj.android/build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I don't know what is problem.

Answer (score 17):

Your project should have a `local.properties` file with an `sdk.dir` line that points to where your Android SDK is installed:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86
```

To create this file if it does not exist, run `android update project -p ...` where the `...` is the path to your project.

Comment: yes I have this file created with "android update project -t android-16 -p .    # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Users/smartmind/Works/SDK/Android/sdk

Comment: BUILD FAILED
/Users/smartmind/Works/SDK/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:569: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/smartmind/Works/Smallthing/cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/platform/android/java/build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var

Comment: @lordubik: Beyond making sure that you are on the latest edition of the Android tools, and making sure that the value of `sdk.dir` is indeed correct, I have no recommendation.

Comment: the android tools are updated with AVD Manager and the sdk.dir is set to Android SDK root. (/Works/Android/sdk)

Comment: ok, resolved with this syntax: ant -Dsdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME -Dtarget=android-16 debug. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 14):

i had the same problem, i resolve the issue using a -Dvar or VM argument.

```
ant debug -Dsdk.dir=$SDK_ROOT
```

where $SDK_ROOT is android SDK path