# Android, Gradle, and Version Control System

Tags: android, version-control, gradle, clearcase

I have an Android application that is being written in Android Studio and is thus setup to use gradle as the build system. The source is in ClearCase. Using the generated gradlew script anyone is able to build the application from the command line without having to first install gradle, but they do have to set up all the Android sdks on their local machine. Ideally, I would like to put the sdk in source control and point gradle at that. There is a local.properties file in my project with the following contents:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

Obviously, I don't want to change this file or check it in to source control, but the comment seems to indicate there is a way to do what I want. My question is does anyone actually know where I can locate "the header note" or what information I will find there?

Comment: Would using a property help? (`-Dsdk.dir=$SDK_ROOT`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16133758/6309)

Answer (score 0):

We are building using the same tools and ran across this issue.  We elected to point sdk.dir to a storage location outside of ClearCase where Gradle can read it.  We also install the Android SDKs on a share so that developers do not have to install them on their own desktop.  This is especially help when we need to build against a variety of SDK versions.